# Rendering engine delay affects measured dimensions in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, backbone.js, rendering

I'm working on a Backbone app that renders several instances of the same view.  Each of the views has a fairly large node tree and I can see that the user agent can't render the views instantaneously.

The issue I'm running into is that when my render callbacks fire, the height is coming through as `0` because the user agent's rendering engine hasn't actually finished rendering the entire view.  If I set a timeout, the correct final height comes through:

```
var ChildView = window.Backbone.View.extend({
   render: function() {
      var template = require('templates/ChildTemplate');
      this.$el.html(template());
      this.afterRender();
   },
   afterRender: function() {
      console.log(this.$el.outerHeight());  // 0
      var _this = this;
      setTimeout(function(){
         console.log(_this.$el.outerHeight()); // 51 (or some non-zero integer)
      }, 100);
      setTimeout(function(){
         console.log(_this.$el.outerHeight()); // 240, full correct height
      }, 300);
   }
});
```

How can I account for this rendering engine delay?

Architecture:

- jquery 1.7.2
- backbone 0.9.9

Comment: It may be more complicated than that. I'm currently running into a problem with Chrome in which changes to DOM elements do not get reflected by their JavaScript DOM properties for at least a few milliseconds.  This practically makes my code a mess; if I have a chain of conditional or looping statements in which I make a DOM modification and then measure something after in JavaScript, I have to break my code into a sequence of blocks that can call each other sequentially via setTimeout.  In this case, the Chrome optimization team has made my life much more difficult than it needs to be.

Answer (score 1):

If the template contains images then i suggest you use the standard jquery `load` function

```
_this.$el.children('img').load(function(){
    //the element should exist now
});
```

Otherwise im not sure what the problem is. Im fairly certain that Underscore's `template` function is synchronous so i wouldnt have suspected any problems there. One thing that might work, and probably makes more sense from a design perspective, would be to make use of `initialize`

```
var ChildView = window.Backbone.View.extend({
   initialize: function(){
       var template = require('templates/ChildTemplate');
       this.renderedTemplate = template();

   },
   render: function() {
      this.$el.html(this.renderedTemplate);
      this.afterRender();
   },
});
```

If you dont want to use the name `renderedTemplate` then thats fine, just make sure not to name it `template` as that is already in use

Comment: The template contains a single image, but we know its dimensions before it loads.  The issue is the total number of `ChildView`s that are rendered, not the content of any one particular view.  My guess is that the user agent is firing some kind of post-render callback to the javascript engine signaling that it can continue execution before it has actually finished rendering the entire node tree.  I don't know how this works under the hood though.

Comment: If youre really desperate for a fix i would consider having a look at [livequery](https://github.com/brandonaaron/livequery). You can provide it with a callback that will execute when the element has been fully loaded into the DOM.